# react-native this.setState causing code to stop running

Tags: reactjs, react-native, websocket

I have a websocket connect set up which react-native successfully connects to. My code is below:

```
export default class Settings extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            questionText: ''
        }
    }

    connect() {

        console.log('connected');
        var socket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/users/');
        socket.onopen = function open() {
            console.log('WebSockets connection created.');

        }

        socket.onmessage = function message(event) {
            var data = JSON.parse(event.data);

            var username = encodeURI(data['username']);
            var question = encodeURI(data['question']);
            console.log('username: ' + username);
            console.log('question: ' + question);
            this.setState({ questionText: question });
            console.log('state: ' + this.state.questionText);

        }
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>{this.state.questionText}</Text>
                <Button
                    title = "Connect"
                    onPress = {this.connect} />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: '#EFEFF4',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center', 
        flex: 1,
    },
});
```

The on message function gets called when a message is sent from the back end and the username and question print to the console as expected. However the state doesn't change and nor does any code run I put after `this.setState({ questionText: question });`

That line seems to cause some issue however there is no error printed to the console. I believe once that state changes then so does the Text component I have being rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting your functions to arrow functions. `this.setState` is probably undefined in the context you have set up. Changing the functions to arrow functions allows `this` to be lexically scoped.

```
...
    connect = () => {

        console.log('connected');
        var socket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/users/');
        socket.onopen = function open() {
            console.log('WebSockets connection created.');

        }

        socket.onmessage = (event) => {
            var data = JSON.parse(event.data);

            var username = encodeURI(data['username']);
            var question = encodeURI(data['question']);
            console.log('username: ' + username);
            console.log('question: ' + question);
            this.setState({ questionText: question });
            console.log('state: ' + this.state.questionText);

        }
    }
...
```

If you don't want to use arrow functions, then you can also use `.bind` to make sure `this` is correct.

```
export default class Settings extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            questionText: ''
        }
        this.connect.bind(this);
    }

    connect() {

        console.log('connected');
        var socket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/users/');
        socket.onopen = function open() {
            console.log('WebSockets connection created.');

        }

        socket.onmessage = function message(event) {
            var data = JSON.parse(event.data);

            var username = encodeURI(data['username']);
            var question = encodeURI(data['question']);
            console.log('username: ' + username);
            console.log('question: ' + question);
            this.setState({ questionText: question });
            console.log('state: ' + this.state.questionText);

        }.bind(this)
    }
...
```